# Find out how many users are online in PHP

Tags: php

i was wondering how you could make a counter that shows how many people are currently on the site.
how to show how many people brousing my site now with page name and how to show recentaly updated pages?

Comment: If someone logs in, add 1. If someone loggs out, subtract 1.

Comment: @YUNOWORK handling the subtraction of those who DON'T log out is the tricky part.

Comment: Keep track of their session information. When is the last time the requested a page (thus activity) and then you can collect (Mysql) all users by looking whom were active in the last five minutes.

Comment: @YUNOWORK Even if it's easy to know the number of logs, il could be difficult to know how many have left (disconnection, just closing the browser or shuting down the computer...)

Comment: Create a cronjob which runs every 10 minutes and checks which user didnt perform an action in that time, if he didnt, hes offline. I dont think thats a big problem to be honest. Or you just use the session functions as already mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `status` (
`session` char(100) NOT NULL default '',
`time` int(11) NOT NULL default '0'
);
```

Status.php

```
<title>User Online</title>
<?php
include ('config.php');
session_start();
$session=session_id();
$time=time();
$time_check=$time-600;
$tbl_name="status";
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect to server");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE session='$session'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count=="0"){
$sql1="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(session, time)VALUES('$session', '$time')";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
}
else {
"$sql2=UPDATE $tbl_name SET time='$time' WHERE session = '$session'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
}
$sql3="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);
$count_user_online=mysql_num_rows($result3);
echo "User online : $count_user_online ";
$sql4="DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE time<$time_check";
$result4=mysql_query($sql4);
mysql_close();
?>
```

Follow my Tutorial for live code and screenshot : http://php.sysaxiom.com/user_online.php

Comment: thanks.how to show a list with online user with page name the are brousing?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **Session** Information for the currently online user's.

[PHP Session Management.](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php)

Comment: thanks.how to show a list with online user with page name the are brousing?

Answer (score 0):

You can only count when a page was loaded by a client, so you'll have to guess how many users are currently browsing your site. For example on ever page load you can save a clients IP address, the page that was requested, and the timestamp. Then you can retrieve that information for the last 2, 5, 10, etc. minutes to get an idea who's currently visiting your site and what page.

Optionally you might want to include session information.

Your second question is very broad and requires more information.

Comment: thanks.how to show a list with online user with page name the are brousing?