# How to show number of users currently online?

Tags: php, live

I created an index.php page (no need login for accessing my index.php page) and I uploaded it on localhost, local users accessing this index.php page. Now I want to see from my admin panel "how many users/people currently accessing my index.php page"

Example: 12 users now online

Is it possible to show number of users currently online? using PHP or another language.

Comment: I’m on Stack Overflow right now. If I put my tablet down, unlocked, for 5 seconds, am I still online? How about 1 minute? 5 minutes? An hour? A day? What if I open a new tab and leave this open in the background? At a high level you just need a counter on the server, a database, the file system, etc. That’s easy. But how to determine when someone is _not_ there is actually the more complicated and subjective problem.

Comment: Check this question
[Find out how many users are online in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22810034/find-out-how-many-users-are-online-in-php)